# Second audio stream gets muted and affected by first audio stream's trimming in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have `filter_complex` and `atrim` options in this `FFmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -i adele.mp3 
-i Ruby\ on\ Rails\ 101-\ What\ is\ Ruby\ on\ Rails_.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:
channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.5,
atrim=end=12,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];
[1:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:
channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.8[a2];
[a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]" \
-strict -2 -map 1:v -map "[out]" -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac output.mp4
```

I'm planning to cut the first audio stream (`adele.mp3`) - just the first 12 seconds of the audio as per `atrim=end=12` filtering.

The first 12 seconds works as expected together with the 2nd audio stream (from the video itself), but after 12 seconds the 2nd audio stream gets muted (no volume at all).

I do not like to mute or remove the audio of the 2nd audio stream. I think it gets affected somewhere else.

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

Here's the logs by the way:

```
ffmpeg version N-60332-ga0d5204 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  4 2014 21:31:51 with Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 63.100 / 52. 63.100
  libavcodec     55. 49.101 / 55. 49.101
  libavformat    55. 29.101 / 55. 29.101
  libavdevice    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
  libavfilter     4.  1.102 /  4.  1.102
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'adele.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : Chasing Pavements
    artist          : Adele
    track           : 3
    album           : 19 (Deluxe Edition)
    date            : 2008
  Duration: 00:03:30.55, start: 0.025056, bitrate: 160 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 159 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 600x600 [SAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : 
      comment         : Other
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Ruby on Rails 101- What is Ruby on Rails_.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2013-12-21 07:56:20
  Duration: 00:05:42.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1214 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1020 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-12-21 07:56:23
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
[Parsed_pan_7 @ 0x7fbe71437480] This syntax is deprecated. Use '|' to separate the list items.
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[Parsed_amerge_6 @ 0x7fbe71436d40] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_6 @ 0x7fbe71436d40] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : Chasing Pavements
    artist          : Adele
    track           : 3
    album           : 19 (Deluxe Edition)
    date            : 2008
    encoder         : Lavf55.29.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 1020 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mp3) -> aformat
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> aformat
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  pan -> Stream #0:1 (libfdk_aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
    Last message repeated 82 times
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory.01 bitrate= 905.2kbits/s    
    Last message repeated 3821 times
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory3.55 bitrate= 131.3kbits/s    
    Last message repeated 3219 times
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory8.51 bitrate=  76.1kbits/s    
    Last message repeated 3247 times
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory4.01 bitrate=  53.5kbits/s    
    Last message repeated 3443 times
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory4.01 bitrate=  40.7kbits/s    
    Last message repeated 380 times
frame=10272 fps=3141 q=-1.0 Lsize=   42882kB time=00:05:42.38 bitrate=1026.0kbits/s    
video:42642kB audio:189kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.120036%
```

Comment: Don't you want the amix filter instead? You can set a duration there.

Comment: Any luck with this ? I am getting the same error